# Need to combine values from multiselect option to form a url with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am using an application that allows real estate searching on my site. The app came with a very limited search functionality form, so I've taken it and tried to enhance it by way of URL parameters that the IDX solution provider provides. One of these parameters is to make a URL and combine multiple city names in order to search for listings in more than one city at a time. I've added a multi select field to the form, but the problem is that each city has to have a sequential number in between < > symbols.

So the search would end up looking like this and the first city has to be number <0>:

www.yourblog.com/idx/?idx-q-Cities<0>=Irvine&idx-q-Cities<1>=Laguna%20Beach

I need a way tfor the options selected in the multiple select field to be combined to achieve the above result.

Here is what the part of the form with the multi select looks like.

```
<form action="http://www.mmysite.com/idx/" method="get"   onsubmit="prepareSearchForm(this)">
<table>
<tr>
<th><label for="idx-q-Cities">Select Your Cities</label></th>   
<td>
<select multiple name="idx-q-Cities"  title="Type or select your cities">
    <option id="idx-q-Cities"  class="idx-q-Cities" value="Abbeville">Abbeville</option><br>
    <option id="idx-q-Cities"  class="idx-q-Cities" value="Abilene">Abilene</option>
</select>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

I had someone helping me try to get this to work, but it was unsuccessful. Here is what they came up with. Maybe it will help.

```
<script>
function prepareSearchForm(form){
var count = 0;

$(form).children('.idx-q-Cities').each(function(i,o){
    var cityDOM = document.createElement('select');
    cityDOM.name = "idx-q-Cities<" + count++ + ">";
    cityDOM.value = o.value;
    form.appendChild(cityDOM);
});

return true;
}
</script>
```

Any ideas on how to correct the above JS or another way to take the multi select options and combine them in order to end up with the URL above?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'll offer you this:

```
function prepareURL() {
    var vals = $('select option:selected').map(
        function(i){
            return $(this).attr('class') + '<' + i + '>=' + $(this).val();
        }).get().join(';');
    var URL = 'www.yourblog.com/idx/' + vals;
    $('#urloutput').text(URL);
}

$('select').click(

function() {
    prepareURL();
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/MTCRW/).

But I'm not sure if you want the first selected 'get' option to be `0` (whether that's Abeline or Abbeville), or if you want the Abbeville to *always* be the `0` option and Abeline to *always* be the `1` option. So I offer you an option based on that possibility too:

```
function prepareURL() {
    var vals = $('select option:selected').map(
        function(){
            return $(this).attr('class') + '<' + $(this).index('select option') + '>=' + $(this).val();
        }).get().join(';');
    var URL = 'www.yourblog.com/idx/' + vals;
    $('#urloutput').text(URL);
}

$('select').click(

function() {
    prepareURL();
});
```

[JS FIddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/MTCRW/1/).

Also, given that this appears to be a GET string, I can't help but feel you should have a `?` in the URL somewhere. But I leave that to you to implement, in case you don't want it there, for some reason.

And, as a (final?) addenda, I'd strongly suggest URL-encoding the `vals` variable before submitting it as a URL:

```
var URL = 'www.yourblog.com/idx/' + encodeURIComponent(vals);
$('#urloutput').text(URL);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/MTCRW/2/).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP then change:

```
<select multiple name="idx-q-Cities" title="Type or select your cities">
```

To:

```
<select multiple name="idx-q-Cities[]" title="Type or select your cities">
```

Your javascript is for sure wrong. Do this on the server end.

Comment: What will adding brackets do?

Comment: It will return that field as an array in PHP. So `$_REQUEST['idx-q-Cities']` will be an array (of the selected fields), not a string.

Comment: Adding the brackets did this:

http://www.mysite.com/idx/?idx-q-Cities[]=Acworth&idx-q-Cities[]=Alpharetta

All it did was change the name to include brackets.

Comment: If I use <> instead of [] then it's almost what I want, but there are still no numbers in there.

Comment: What is your backend? What is generating the url string? Are you using PHP or not? You never answered me.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see a question from you. My server is running PHP.

Comment: Please include the section of PHP code that generates the redirect and then I can give you a proper answer.